# compare the first word from 2 text files

Tags: python

I have these 2 csv files. The first word is the "key" and I need to compare the old file t1 with the new one t2. If the key match, I need to display the content from new file.

```
cat /tmp/t1.txt
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, m, p

cat /tmp/t2.txt
d, x, y
g, h, i
```

But the way this loop is written, it shows the entry from old file for the key 'g' while it works correctly for the key 'd'.

```
with open("/tmp/t1.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("/tmp/t2.txt", "r") as n:
        for nline in n:
            for fline in f:
                if nline.split()[0] == fline.split()[0]:
                    print("nline", nline)
                else:
                    print("fline", fline)
```

The result is:

```
fline a, b, c
nline d, x, y
fline g, m, p
```

The last line should look like this:

> nline g, h, i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to reopen the file once you read through it:

```
with open("/tmp/t2.txt", "r") as n:
    for nline in n:
        with open("/tmp/t1.txt", "r") as f:   # <<-- moved this line here
            for fline in f:
                # some comparisons here
```

Another good approach would be to read both files once, and then compare the data:

```
with open("/tmp/t1.txt", "r") as fin :
    data1 = fin.readlines()

with open("/tmp/t2.txt", "r") as fin :
    data2 = fin.readlines()

for nline in data1 :
    for fline in data2 :
        # put your logic here
```

---

ok, answering the question from the comments:

```
with open("/tmp/t1.txt", "r") as fin :
    data1 = [ (i[0], i) for i in fin.readlines() if len(i) > 3 ]

with open("/tmp/t2.txt", "r") as fin :
    data2 = { i[0] : i for i in fin.readlines() if len(i) > 3 }

for key,value in data1 :
    print data2[key] if key in data2 else value
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using `pandas`

- Caveat: keys in `t2` are unique
- Generates a dataframe with rows updated where the `t1` key matches the `t2` key

```py
import pandas as pd

# read files
t1 = pd.read_csv('t1.txt', header=None)
t2 = pd.read_csv('t2.txt', header=None)

# t2 to a dict
t2_d = t2.set_index(0, drop=False).to_dict(orient='index')

# look for t1 in t2_d
t1.apply(lambda x: t2_d[x[0]] if x[0] in t2_d else x, axis=1)


    0   1   2
0   a   b   c
1   d   x   y
2   g   h   i
```

### Optionally

- This option adds a column, `in_t2` to indicate whether `t1` is in `t2`
- Create `updated` and join it to `t1` to easily verify updated values

```py
# read files
t1 = pd.read_csv('t1.txt', header=None)
t2 = pd.read_csv('t2.txt', header=None)

# add Boolean column
t1['in_t2'] = t1[0].isin(t2[0])

# t2 to a dict
t2_d = t2.set_index(0, drop=False).to_dict(orient='index')

# look for t1 in t2_d
updated = t1.iloc[:, :-1].apply(lambda x: t2_d[x[0]] if x[0] in t2_d else x, axis=1)

# join t1 and updated
pd.concat([t1, updated], axis=1)

    0   1   2   in_t2   0   1   2
0   a   b   c   False   a   b   c
1   d   e   f   True    d   x   y
2   g   m   p   True    g   h   i
```